# C# WindowsForms UserControl's Controls Designer Support

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, editing

What I am looking for is the same type of designer support for controls inside a usercontrol. ie - resizing a textbox, moving a label, that are inside a usercontrol **after placeing the usercontrol on to a form**.

What I've been able to do...

1. create a usercontrol
2. use the designer to add controls to the it
3. create a new window forms app
4. add the usercontrol to the toolbox
5. drag and drop the control on the a form

where I am stuck...

1. edit the usercontrols controls. IE - being able to resize a textbox that is inside the usercontrol using the designer.

I found a similar question on stack that was never answered. So if I am being too vague you can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359772/example-make-constituent-controls-in-a-usercontrol-editable.

Thank you.

Comment: Anchors in your usercontrol won't control the textbox size the way you need it to?

Comment: I can edit them from the designer for the usercontrol. But once I add it to a form I can't even select the textbox to get the anchors.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the VS IDE, Just like how you cant move the position of the label on a Button, The UserControl is complied an cannot be changed from anothet application, You could however expose Public properties so they can be ajusted from the properties window, but I doubt you will be able to do in the designer itself using the mouse to drag inner controls

Comment: Thanks... thats the work around I thought I'd have to turn to if I wanted to continue down this road. :)

Comment: Actually, I think you may achieve that functionality by 1) Create your own designer for your user control; 2) Use WndProc method of designer to control for dragging mouse events on elements of UserControl => changing their properties. It's quite complicated task and you should clearly answer to yourself - whether you really need that functionality. Otherwise use public properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading Nikita's comment I was able to find Microsoft support page on creating a custom designer for controls.

Here's a quote if your interested on how the designed-time support works

> The design-time support for components in the .NET Framework, however, is not defined exclusively by a design tool such as Microsoft Visual Studio .NET. Rather, the development environment supports the extension and definition of design-time behavior by classes such as designers that provide design-time support for components. Support for extensible and customizable design mode behavior is an integrated part of the .NET Framework. Tools such as Visual Studio .NET also provide a range of design-time services that designers can use.

This is the webpage if you like to continue reading and view samples from Microsoft

[Enhancing Design-Time Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Everything seems complicated when you just start learning it, heres a working code sample for a UserControl that has a PictureBox and a Label on it. Both controls can be edited during design time, ie. resizing and repositioning, and expose all their events and properties if you click on them.

You will need to add a reference to System.Design, which can only be referenced if you are not targeting ".Net Client Profile." You can change you target profile in Proprieties/Application/TargetFramework.

Add a usercontrol to your project and add a class to handle it's designer. Double click the usercontrol and then add a label and picture box from the toolbar.

Next open that class you create to be it's designer. Add this...

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);

        if (this.Control is MyUserControl)  // replace this with your usercontrol type
        {
            // cast this.Control to you type of usercontrol to get at it's
            // controls easier
            var i = this.Control as MyUserControl; // replace ***

            this.EnableDesignMode(i.label1, "unique_name1");
            this.EnableDesignMode(i.pictureBox1, "unique_name2");
        }
    }
```