# Edit my control from designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I created control which contains a label and a textbox next to it:
[image: PhoneControl]

The hierarchy look like that:

```
Panel
    ->Panel
          ->TextBox
          ->Label
```

I want to be able to custom the it on designer like change the textbox and label size and the text of the textbox.

Is there a easier way to do it without the needs to add property for each datamember of each control and calculate the sizes?

I have this code right now:

```
    public override string Text
    {
        set { this.PhoneLabel.Text = value; }
        get { return this.PhoneLabel.Text; }
    }

    public Size SizePhone
    {
        set { PhoneTextBox.Size = value; }
        get { return PhoneTextBox.Size; }
    }

    public Size SizeLabel
    {
        set { PhoneLabel.Size = value; }
        get { return PhoneLabel.Size; }
    }

    public Point LocationLabel
    {
        set { PhoneLabel.Location = value; }
        get { return PhoneLabel.Location; }
    }
```

I want to change the size with the mouse like I design a form

Thank you

Comment: By Designer you mean e.g. a Form Designer not the UC Designer? Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330625/c-sharp-windowsforms-usercontrols-controls-designer-support) post?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thank you